# Variable inside number

Tags: php, syntax, floating-point

so I have this little piece of code and I cannot make it work.
I just want to insert my integer into float plain number.

```
// Should return: 1.50
$var = 50;
echo 1.$var;
```

I tried to isolate variable like `echo 1.($var);`, but nothing appears to work.

What I am doing wrong? I believe there is syntax workaround.

Comment: Do you want to make it a float (which seems senseless) or you just want to print `1.50`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the sole purpose is to print `1.50` only, you can concatenate a string `1.` with the `$var` like:

```
<?php
$var = 50;
echo "1." . $var;
?>
```

Or If you want it to be converted into float:

```
<?php
$var = 50;
$one = 1;
echo (float) $one. '.' .$var;
?>
```

**EDIT:**

Moving forward from the comment you made under this answer, this is how it should be done:

```
<?php
$a = 600;
$b = 5;
echo number_format(ceil($a * (float)('1.' . $b)));
?>
```

Output:

```
900
```

[PHP Fiddle](http://codepad.org/pWQkHVKt)

Comment: `number_format(ceil($a*'1'.$b))` here is my code, where $a is 600 and $b is my procent, for example 5. So it should do the math 600 * 1.5 but it does not, it returns much larger number..

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want to do.

If you want to just print `1.50`, just do:

```
$var = 50;
echo '1.'.$var;
```

If you want to convert it to a float number, use this:

```
$var = 50;
$number = 1;
$float = (float) $number.'.'.$var;
```